# Data is not loading in UIpickerview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I am trying to load the data from web service into UI picker view. It shows up as blank. Below is my code.

```
NSMutableArray * flooring;
NSDictionary *dictionary;
NSString *floorname;
NSString *floorid;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    floorname = @"Name";
    floorid   = @"IntFloorId";
    NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://123.63.83.11:8002/api/Floor/LoadFloorType"];
    NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                          [NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                      jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
        NSString *Name = [dataDict objectForKey:@"Name"];
        NSString *floorid1 = [dataDict objectForKey:@"IntFloorId"];
        dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     Name,floorname,floorid1,floorid, nil];
        [flooring addObject:dictionary];
    }


-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return flooring.count;
}
    - (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component  
{
    NSDictionary *tmpDict = [flooring objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString * f = [tmpDict objectForKey:@"Name"];return f;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the containing class conform to both a UIPickerViewDelegate and a UIPickerViewDataSource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flooring` is never initialized so it appears empty.

Add:

```
flooring = [NSMutableArray array];
```

in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Also learn to use your debugger. You would have found this long ago if you debugged your code.

Comment: Nice. its working my mistake.I forget to initilaize the array.One more doubt?Shall I ask in comment?

Comment: If you have a simple question directly related to this one, you can ask me in a comment here. If it's unrelated then you should post a new question after you've done sufficient research.